# Is it allright to wrap H1/H2/H3 tag around a multicolumn design div for headlines?

Tags: seo, search-engine, html-heading

is the following syntax good to go to emhpasize a multicolumn headline totalling around 20 ~ 30 words? I dont want to use CSS3 multicolumns since it is not supported in IE9 etc.

```
<H3>
     <div id="headingLeft" >blaa blaa blaa</div> 
     <div id="headingRight">blue blue blue</div> 
</H3>
```

Comment: While not an answer to your question (hence a comment), have you considered using [html5's `header` element](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/), and the html5 doctype, of course?

Comment: @David Thomas, THATS what I was looking for! place it as an answer sothat I can accept is as an answer! The upvote in your answer would be fot the quality of the link you added. Explains everything in very clear language!

Comment: I'd be glad to do so; and thank you, for the kind words. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to a request from the OP:

> [That's] what I was looking for! Place it as an answer so that I can accept is as an answer! The up-vote in your answer would be for the quality of the link you added. Explains everything in very clear language!

Have you considered using [html5's `header` element](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/), and the html5 `doctype` of course?

Answer (score 1):

The headings shouldn't have div's inside of them. Maybe something more like this... The data in the two headings must not be too closely related, otherwise you shouldn't be splitting them apart at all. I'm assuming it's like a callout or something.

```
<div class="headings">
     <h3 id="headingLeft" >blaa blaa blaa</h3> 
     <h4 id="headingRight">blue blue blue</h4> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `<div>` with a class associated to it (or a css selector) instead of using H3 this way.  I'm not sure this is the more SEO-friendly way of doing what you want to do.

```
<div class="headline">
  <div id="headingLeft">blaa blaa blaa</div>
  <div id="headingRight">blue blaa blue</div>
</div>
```

It doesn't seem that you're using `H3` in a semantic way.